# Read 10000+ rows from Excel using OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

Below code snippet working fine for reading some 5000-6000 rows but not for more than 10000. when I use SELECT * FROM Sheet1$A1:DC20000, dtdata has only 8327 rows.

```
string connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + templatepath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
                        string Extension = Path.GetExtension(templatepath);
       if (Extension == ".xls")
           connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + templatepath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstr); 

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Sheet1$A1:DC20000";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);
                            cmd.CommandTimeout = 5000;
                            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                            da.Fill(dtdata);
                            dtdata.TableName = "Table0";
                            dsdata.Tables.Add(dtdata);
```

Comment: And how many rows are in your excel file? (I mean rows with data)

Comment: 20000 rows with data

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but the syntax used to identify the range to load seems to be wrong. Can you try with _[Sheet1$A1:DC20000]_ (adding square brackets around the sheet/range ?

Comment: Also you don't need to use the JET OleDb provider to read xls, the ACE.12.0 is able to read those files.

Comment: Maybe the timeout is too small.

Comment: @Steve -                                                                                                                 Not sure about [Sheet1$A1:DC20000], since this is working fine for 8000+ rows. I would give ACE.12.0  a try - thanks

Comment: @jdweng                                                                                                                                   time out seems fine - thanks